# css file is opening in plain text if extension is missed from URL

Tags: php, css

In my website folder, I have certain files, including:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/admin.php
http://www.mywebsite.com/admin.css
```

I have noticed that if I want to get to the admin page, to log in to the admin area, but if I accidently miss the ".php" extension, and type...

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/admin
```

Then my browser opens up the "admin.css" file in the browser in plain text.

How can I prevent this happening?

Comment: This is caused by your webserver configuration. Which webserver do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running PHP under Apache, add the `-MultiViews` option of Apache configuration will solve your problem.